# unable to understand syntax for the query

Tags: oracle

Below SQL statement is changing default date format for the session:

```
 alter session set
     nls_date_format = ' " ' 'union select uname,0,null from user_pw--" ';
```

But I'm unable to understand the syntax why double quotes are used here (").

For example: I can use below statement to change date format to 'DD-MON-YYYY':

```
--Query: 
ALTER SESSION set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
```

Here no double quotes are used.

Comment: Looks like a SQL Injection attack... See [Tom Kyte's blog](http://tkyte.blogspot.it/2011/02/interesting-read-followup.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm reading his book and same topic but unable to understand the syntax. Why double quotes has been used here?